# Add legend in the tooltip

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I displayed a graphic with Hightcart. I work with R.

I added tooltips which we can see all the y values for the same point x:

```
graph$tooltip(
  formatter = "#!function () {
  var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %Y', this.x) + '</b>';
  $.each(this.points, function () {
  s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' +
  '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y * 100, 2) + '%</b>';
  }); 
  return s;
}!#", shared = TRUE 
  , crosshairs = TRUE
  , hideDelay = 3000
)
```

So for one tooltip, I have around 10 values in this form:

```
ITEM1 : XX%
ITEM2 : YY%
...
ITEM10 : ZZ%*
```

Thus it's difficult to identify which value belong which curve. For this reason, I would like to add in the tooltips, the legend before the values:

```
[yellow circle] ITEM1 : XX%
[blue circle]   ITEM2 : YY%
...
[green circle]  ITEM10 : ZZ%*
```

Answer (score -1):

If someone have this problem, you must add :

```
this.series.color + '\">\u25CF</span> '+  this.series.name
```